# How to upload an image with html and php?

Tags: php, html, image

I'm trying to upload an image using html and php but when I try it, it gives me always an error.

I've already seen in the php.ini file if the upload option is active and it is, also de max-size is at 1000M

HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="php/uploadLocal.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code

```php
<?php 
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
      echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just restarted pc and it worked, simply frustrating

Comment: why you give this as answer?

Comment: @MohitKumar so other people don't waste their time trying to find an error where there is none

Comment: you have to put it in comment also.